# If $A$ is nonsingular and $B$ is nonsingular show that $AB$ is nonsingular.

Tags: matrices

I don't understand how to prove this statement for all cases of $A$ and $B$. Can someone help?

Comment: try using determinants. what do you know about det(a) and det(b) and how do they relate to det(ab)?

Comment: What is $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})$?

Comment: Let's see... I know that for two nonsingular matrices A and B, det(A) * det(B) = det(AB) (right?). Since they are nonsingular, det(A) =/= 0 and det(B) =/= 0, so the det(AB) cannot equal zero either. And if it doesn't equal zero, it's nonsingular. Did I get that right?

Comment: yeah, that proof should be adequate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one way to skin a cat:

1. Take any $0\neq x\in\mathbb R^n$. Because $B$ is nonsingular, $y=Bx\neq 0$. Because $A$ is nonsingular, $Ay\neq 0$, meaning $ABx=A(Bx)=Ay\neq 0$. This is true for all $x\neq 0$, so $AB$ is nonsingular.
2. A is invertible, therefore there exists $A^{-1}$. $B$ is invertible, therefore there exists $B^{-1}$. Since
   $$(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})=A(BB^{-1})A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I,$$
   this means $AB$ has an inverse. Only nonsingular matrices have inverses, therefore $AB$ is nonsingular.
3. $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$. Since $A$ and $B$ are invertible, $\det(A)\neq 0$ and $\det(B)\neq 0$. This means that $\det(AB)\neq 0$. Only nonsingular matrices have nonzero determinants, therefore $AB$ is invertible.